# viewWithTag only updating last tag in set

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, tags, uilabel

I am trying to create series of labels with tags, then update the text.  But, only the last label ever gets updated.  How do I update a all of them, or a specific tagged label?

This example should makes 4 labels with the numbers 1,2,3,4 in them.  Then is should overwrite them with A,B,C,D.  Only the 4th label is overwritten.

Thoughts?

```
int x = 10, y=10, w = 80, h = 30;
for(int i=1; i<= 4  ; i++)
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h ) ;
    myLab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [myLab setTag:i] ;
    [myLab setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]] ;
    [myLab setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    [self.view addSubview:myLab];
    x += 158;
}


for (int i = 1; i <=4; i++){
    UILabel *textField = (UILabel*)[myLab viewWithTag:i];
    [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",i+64]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the class reference of UIView to get more explanation about viewWithTag method: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

It is mentioned there that this viewWithTag method searches the current view and all of its subviews for the specified view. With your current implementation, the specified view is myLab (which is assigned to the last (4th) UILabel after the for loop), not the self.view where it contains all the labels.

Change the looking of the label to `[self.view viewWithTag:i]` to search for label with certain tag under self.view since you are adding all those labels into self.view subviews.

```
for (int i = 1; i <=4; i++){
    UILabel *textField = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",i+64]];
}
```